# Output of \layout as plaintext

Tags: margins

Is it possible to get the dimensions generated from the `\layout` command as plain text, so it can be used to set appropriate sizes when generating graphics in programs like octave.

```matlab
pointsize= 0.35145980351/10;
% 373 happens to be the width of the text column in this particular
% case but it would change with different layout options, but I would 
% like to retrieve it from LaTeX instead
textwidth = 373*pointsize;
figwidth=0.8*textwidth;
figheight=0.6*figwidth;
fig=figure('paperunits','centimeters','papersize'...
    ,[figwidth figheight],'paperposition',[0 0 figwidth figheight]);
```

To get something that it is to pares, I tried this:

```latex
\newcommand{\geomdump}{
\newwrite\geometry
\openout\geometry=geometry\thesection.txt
\write\geometry{tex_section=\thesection;}
\write\geometry{tex_paperwidth=\paperwidth;}
\write\geometry{tex_paperheight=\paperheight;}
\write\geometry{tex_textwidth=\textwidth;}
\write\geometry{tex_textheight=\textheight;}
\write\geometry{tex_oddsidemargin=\oddsidemargin;}
\write\geometry{tex_evensidemargin=\evensidemargin;}
\write\geometry{tex_topmargin=\topmargin;}
\write\geometry{tex_headheight=\headheight;}
\write\geometry{tex_headsep=\headsep;}
\write\geometry{tex_topskip=\topskip;}
\write\geometry{tex_footskip=\footskip;}
\write\geometry{tex_marginparwidth=\marginparwidth;}
\write\geometry{tex_marginparsep=\marginparsep;}
\write\geometry{tex_columnsep=\columnsep;}
\write\geometry{tex_hoffset=\hoffset;}
\write\geometry{tex_voffset=\voffset;}
\write\geometry{tex_mag=\mag;}
\closeout\geometry
}
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\oldsection{#1}
\geomdump
}
```

This is how the output looks (for section 1)

```
tex_section=1;
tex_paperwidth=\paperwidth ;
tex_paperheight=\paperheight ;
tex_textwidth=\textwidth ;
tex_textheight=\textheight ;
tex_oddsidemargin=\oddsidemargin ;
tex_evensidemargin=\evensidemargin ;
tex_topmargin=\topmargin ;
tex_headheight=\headheight ;
tex_headsep=\headsep ;
tex_topskip=\topskip ;
tex_footskip=\footskip ;
tex_marginparwidth=\marginparwidth ;
tex_marginparsep=\marginparsep ;
tex_columnsep=\columnsep ;
tex_hoffset=\hoffset ;
tex_voffset=\voffset ;
tex_mag=\mag ;
```

Questions:

- The macros for extracting lengths does not work here, but the section counter is available. How can I fix this issue?
- Now I get one file per section. Is it possible to append to a file instead of creating new files?

Comment: You can use `\usepackage[pass,verbose]{geometry}`, that will output all pagination parameters in the `.log` file.

Comment: @egreg There they are, but it is not a big improvement, since it is hard to pars the log file. But I can perhaps \renewcommand section...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.

`\openout` and `\closeout` outside the command otherwise the file will be overwritten.

`\the<\length>`: to type value of length.

**Note** this is a bad way to redefine `\section`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newwrite\mtgeometry
\immediate\openout\mtgeometry=mtfile.txt

\newcommand{\geomdump}{%
\immediate\write\mtgeometry{
tex_section=\thesection; ^^J
tex_paperwidth=\the\paperwidth; ^^J
tex_paperheight=\the\paperheight; ^^J
tex_textwidth=\the\textwidth; ^^J
tex_textheight=\the\textheight; ^^J
tex_oddsidemargin=\the\oddsidemargin; ^^J
tex_evensidemargin=\the\evensidemargin; ^^J
tex_topmargin=\the\topmargin; ^^J
tex_headheight=\the\headheight; ^^J
tex_headsep=\the\headsep; ^^J
tex_topskip=\the\topskip; ^^J
tex_footskip=\the\footskip; ^^J
tex_marginparwidth=\the\marginparwidth; ^^J
tex_marginparsep=\the\marginparsep; ^^J
tex_columnsep=\the\columnsep; ^^J
tex_hoffset=\the\hoffset; ^^J
tex_voffset=\the\voffset; ^^J
tex_mag=\the\mag; ^^J}}

\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
\oldsection{#1}\geomdump}
\begin{document}
bla bla
\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\immediate\closeout\mtgeometry
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\openout` *can* be inside the command; it seems that (for reasons I don't understand) a new file is to be created at each `\section` command, so the file name should depend on the section number. Definitely `\newwrite` must go outside `\geomdump`, which should end with `\immediate\closeout\mtgeometry`.

Comment: @egreg  second question ask for only one file.

Comment: @touhami I got som strange error when I tried to move the file opening outside the macro. I would also like something to close the file automatically.